# Program is supposed to split DNA into groups of 3 but instead sees the sequence as too long

Tags: java, string, bluej

For simplicity's sake, I pasted the whole thing in but the test case that we are supposed to use is CAGTTTAGCTAGAAA and when I do this I get an error because it says its too long but where the error is, that is only supposed to group them into 3 so later on they can be converted based on their groups.

```
public class Soutar_bioinformatics
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            //Variable declaration
            int DNAstrandlength, DNAsplit;
            String strandDNA;
            Scanner DNAInfo = new Scanner (System.in);
            //Welcome
            System.out.println ("**********************************************");
            System.out.println ("Welcome to Matthew's Bioinformatics");
            System.out.println ("**********************************************");

            //Input
            System.out.println ("Please enter a DNA Strand!");
            strandDNA = DNAInfo.next();
            DNAstrandlength = strandDNA.length();

            if  (DNAstrandlength % 3 != 0)
            {
                System.out.println ("The DNA sequence enterered is not valid, please insert a correct sequence.");
                strandDNA = DNAInfo.next();
            }

            //Processing 
            ArrayList<String> DNAarray = DNAsplit(strandDNA); // Calls the DNA split method

            //Goodbye
            System.out.println ("**********************************************");
            System.out.println ("Thank you for using Matthew's Program");
            System.out.println ("**********************************************");

        } 
        private static ArrayList<String> DNAsplit (String text)
        { 
            ArrayList<String> DNAsplit = new ArrayList <String>();

            for (int i = 0; 1 < text.length(); i += 3)
            {
                DNAsplit.add(text.substring(i, Math.min(i + 3, text.length())));
            }

            String [] codonArray = DNAsplit.toArray (new String[DNAsplit.size()]);
            System.out.print ("\f");
            System.out.println ("The Amino acids are: ");

            for (int j = 0; j < codonArray.length; j = j + 1)
            {


            //First Column
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("TTT", "F");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("TCT", "S");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("TAT", "Y");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("TGT","C");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("CTT", "L");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("CCT", "P");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("CAT", "H");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("CGT", "R");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("ATT" , "I");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("ACT", "T");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("AAT", "N");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("AGT", "S");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("GTT", "V");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("GCT" , "A");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("GAT" , "D");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("GGT", "G");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("TTT", "F");
            //Second Column
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("TCT", "S");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("TAT", "Y");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("TGT", "C");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("CTT", "L");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("CCT", "P");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("CAT", "H");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("CGT", "R");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("ATT" , "I");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("ACT", "T");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("AAT", "N");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("AGT", "S");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("GTT", "V");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("GCT" ,"A");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("GAT" , "D");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace("GGT", "G");
            //Third Coloumn
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("TTA", "L");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("TCA", "S");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("TAA", "STOP");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("TGA", "STOP");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("CTA", "L");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("CCA", "P");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("CAA", "Q");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("CGA", "R");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("ATA", "I");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("ACA", "T");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("AAA", "K");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("AGA", "R");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("GTA", "V");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("GCA", "A");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("GAA", "E");
            codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("GGA", "E");
            //Fourth Column
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("TTG", "L");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("TCG", "S");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("TAG", "STOP");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("TGG", "W");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("CTG", "L");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("CCG", "P");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("CAG", "Q");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("CGG", "R");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("ATG", "M");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("ACG", "T");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("AAG", "K");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("AGG", "R");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("GTG", "V");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("GCG", "A");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("GAG", "E");
        codonArray[j] = codonArray[j].replace ("GGG", "G");


        System.out.print (codonArray[j] + " ");
        if (codonArray[j].contains ("STOP"))
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    return DNAsplit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "says its too long"?

Comment: yea so my input is clashing with the array list and it sees that the DNA sequence is over 3 characters which is the group and instead of grouping it stops the program

Comment: Can you copy/paste the actual error, along with pointing out which line(s) it's occurring on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple error on your code in DNASplit Function.

```
        for (int i = 0; 1 < text.length(); i += 3)
        {
            DNAsplit.add(text.substring(i, Math.min(i + 3, text.length())));
        }
```

that 1 in for loop should be i.